# how add custom format in Wsying Editor to selected text before br tag

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor

I am adding custom format for Wsying Editor in Wordpress as follows:

```
array(
      'title' => 'Content Sub Heading',
      'block' => 'h3',
      'classes' => 'h3'//
     )
```

It's working fine but the issue is whenever there is text as follows.

```
<p>custom sub heading<br/>not custom sub heading</p>
```

I can't add `h3` or any other `html` tag to 'custom sub heading' text. Is there any way to do this without the removal of `br` tag?

Any advice/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be barking up the wrong tree but would you not have to use a span class for embedded text formatting within another tag?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle even if i use span it results like below.
<p><span class="h3">custom sub heading<br/>not custom sub heading</span></p>
but what I really want is
<p><span class="h3">>custom sub heading</span><br/>not custom sub heading</p>